# return value for int main

Tags: c++, return, return-value

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool running = 1;

void newGameFunc();

void titleFunc();

int userInput = 0;
int playerInfo[2]; //player info, change variable to number of options for the player
int main() {

void titleFunc(); {
    cout << "\t\t\t\t game dialogue \n\n\n";

    cout <<  "\game dialogue";

    cin >> userInput;

    if (userInput == 1) {
        newGameFunc();
    }
    else {
        running = 0;
    }
        return 0;
}

titleFunc();

return 0;

void newGameFunc();{
    cout << "game dialogue \n";
    cout << "game dialogue.\n";
    cout << "game dialogue";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[0] = userInput;

    cout << "game dialogue\n";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[1] = userInput;
    return;  <--- the problem
}

while (running) {
}

return 0;
}
```

i started programming in c++ yesterday running off of online tutorials. this is what i have so far but something is wrong with the return value. its says 'main': function must return a value. i pointed out the problem in the code. i put a value before and it comes up with more errors. can sombody please help me?

Comment: You can't have local functions - titleFunc and newGameFunc cannot be inside main so stick them just above the line that says `int main() {` and the declaration of the functions shouldn't have a semicolon between the function and it's body so, for example, `void titleFunc(); {` should be written as `void titleFunc() {`

Comment: If you are doing this based on online tutorials, please read the tutorial better, and notice what Jerry Jeremiah says. I cannot imagine the code in the tutorial is the same as yours.

Comment: now it is telling me i have a bunch of errors. i think i may be following a faulty tutorial. do you have any suggestions for a good tut on programming a text based adventure type game?

Comment: it is exactly the same

Comment: the problem is i have no prior experience in programming. i download vs studios and went prom there

Comment: maybe your missing a page?  the code is clearly nonsensical and must have some copy paste issues from the tutorial or a superbly bad tutorial

Comment: Showing the error messages will help as well.

Comment: There are many conceptual misunderstandings in your code. You'd be best off, if you tried to understand what functions are, how functions are declared and what the meaning of the main function is.

Comment: i don't even know where to begin with c++ then.

Comment: Don't begin like this. Begin with a good book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend following a nice tutorial like this [tutorial on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/).
This code will compile and run, but most probably it will not do what you expected it to do. For example,

```
while (running) {
}
```

This code will never stop, because the variable running is never set to 0/false. It should be set to 0 in the loop it self. The following code is not very functional right now, but it compiles :)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool running = 1;

void newGameFunc();

void titleFunc();

int userInput = 0;
int playerInfo[2]; // player info, change variable to number of options for the player

int main() {
    titleFunc(); // You call/execute the function titlefunc
    return 0; // and after that return from the main function
              // this ends your program/game
}

void titleFunc() {
    cout << "\t\t\t\t game dialogue \n\n\n";

    cout <<  "game dialogue";

    cin >> userInput;

    if (userInput == 1) {
        newGameFunc();
    } else {
        running = 0;
    }
    return; // A void function does not return anything
}

void newGameFunc() {
    cout << "game dialogue \n";
    cout << "game dialogue.\n";
    cout << "game dialogue";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[0] = userInput;

    cout << "game dialogue\n";
    cin >> userInput;
    playerInfo[1] = userInput;
    while (running) {
        cin >> userInput;
        if(userInput==0) {
            running = 0;
        }
        // Other code that should be executed while the game loop is active
    }
    return;
}
```

Good luck with your game!, and with your life as a programmer :)

Answer (score 1):

You're making many syntactic errors in your code. I recommend not doing online tutorials and going through a book like Accelerated C++ by Koenig. Otherwise, if you can't get access to this book, check out the books in this thread on SO: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: unfortunately those cost money. which at this very moment i do not have extra money to spend on it.